# Probability of a light bulb still working after 800 hours is 0.2 and there are 3 lightbulbs in the hallway

Tags: probability

I recently encountered this question:

**The probability that the bulb will work longer than 800 hours is $0.2$. We have three bulbs in the hallway. What is the probability that after 800 hours of service at least one of them will still work ?**

I understand that in calculating the probability that at least one light bulb **is still working** is equal to $1 - P(\text{all light bulbs fail})$.

Answer should be: $1-(1-0.2)(1-0.2)(1-0.2) = 0.488$

However, I want to try this by not doing the reverse (taking $1$ and deducting with probability of all light bulb fails).

How do I do this? What if there are 5 light bulbs in the hallway and I want to know the probability of at least 2 of them still working?

Comment: Break into cases for the number of lightbulbs that make it to 800 hours, then sum all those up.

Comment: In R, `sum(dbinom(2:5, 5, .2))` returns $0.26272.$ By hand, $X\sim\mathsf{Binom}(5,.2):$ use its PMF and sum $P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5).$

Answer (score 1):

You should be familiar with binomal distribution.

Let X be the number of lightbulbs still work after 800 hours.

$P(X \geq 2) = 1 - P(X = 0) - P(X = 1)$

So what is the probability that no light bulb works after 800 hours? Easy. It's $(1-0.2)^5$.

When it comes to the probability that only one light bulb works after 800 hours, it becomes a bit more complicated.

So remember we have 5 light bulbs at the beginning (11111). If after 800 hours, only one light bulb lasts, it could be the first light bulb (10000), it could be the second one (01000) and so on. There are $5 \choose 1$ possible situations. Each one has the probability of $(1-0.2)^4.0.2$.

$P(X \geq 2) = 1 - P(X = 0) - P(X = 1) = 1 - (1-0.2)^5 - 5.(1-0.2)^4.0.2 = 0.26272$

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to do $(1-q)$, consider all cases satisfying the condition "at least" -

i) Probability that exactly one bulb is working $= 3C1 \times 0.2 \times 0.8 \times 0.8$

ii) Probability that exactly two of three bulbs are working $= 3C2 \times 0.2 \times 0.2 \times 0.8$

iii) Probability that all three bulbs are working $= 3C3 \times 0.2 \times 0.2 \times 0.2$

Add all of them up.

You can do the same way for $5$ bulbs and at least $2$ of them working.